# App is crashing when swift 3 @obj inference is set to "default" because of RealmSwift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, swift4

When I am setting the Swift 3 `@obj` inference to "Default" then the app is crashing and giving the error:

> Primary key property 'id' does not exist on object

And also I can't see any object in Realm Browser. But when I set the Swift 3 `@obj` inference to "On" then it is working perfectly but is taking too much time to load the screen. It was working perfectly in Swift 3 but when I upgraded to Swift 4 this problem start coming. Can someone please help me? Thanks.

I have attached the image of realm browser when the Swift 3 `@obj` inference set to default.

[image: This is the image of realm browser when swift 3 @obj inference is set to default]

Comment: Any answers on this question are welcome, but this question is also being tracked on Realm's issue tracker here: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have marked all my model properties with "@objc dynamic" and now everything is working perfectly in my case.